# How to convert dataframe columns which contains specific string to each columns to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a dataframe with only one row which contains columns such as subscription_id_avg, subscription_id_std etc.., around 84 columns. Each column contains a mean and a standard deviation. I want to convert this dataframe to a nested dictionary such as

{"subscription_id" : {"avg": 0.36, "std": 1.5}}

How do I split the column names and convert it into a nested dictionary form?

Comment: please add a sample of your dataframe to the question (as text, not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `_std` and `_avg` are in every column name so `column_name[:-4]` will give the desired property name. For example, `subscription_id_avg[:-4]` will yeild `subscription_id`. Using this, we can get the keys for dictionary.

```
dict = {}
for cl in df.columns:
   key_name = cl[:-4]
   if dict.get(key_name) is None:
       dict[key_name] = {cl[-3:]: df[cl][0]}
   else:
       dict[key_name][cl[-3:]] = df[cl][0]
```

Here dict will be the required python dictionary. Hope this will help.
This will work only if `_avg` and `_std` are the only suffixes in column names.